# Error code installing TensorLy with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pip

I am trying to install [TensorLy](http://tensorly.org/stable/installation.html) using pip however I get the following error message:

[image]

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: It means that `TensorLy` requires `mxnet` to be installed, but did not specify `mxnet` as a dependency. Just install `mxnet`: `pip install --user mxnet`, then retry `pip install --user tensorly`.

Comment: Actually, the current version of `tensorly` is 0.4.2, you have an old version in cache. Run `pip install --user --no-cache-dir tensorly` to ignore the cached packages and install the latest version. My comment above applies only if you explicitly want to install an old version 0.2.0.

Comment: @hoefling so when I ran `pip install --user --no-cache-dir tensorly` it gave me the same error so I did your previous instructions and got tensorly 0.2.0 (thank you!) but how do you know the latest is v0.4.2 ? When I try `pip install tensorly --upgrade` it says it's up-to-date

Comment: Just peaked over https://pypi.org/project/tensorly/#files, latest version is 0.4.2. I guess you can only install 0.2.0 because you're on Python 2 and 0.2.0 is the last version supporting Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you're trying to install Tensorly using python 2 instead of Python 3.
You can see in [Tensorly github](https://github.com/tensorly/tensorly) that it requires Python 3.